# Cannot get updated state value inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to update state which is array of object by maping through the previous state value and i've logged before jxs return and another log inside useEffect with dependency of same state value. I logged update state value on log before jsx return but logged old state value inside useEffect.

```js
 setSelectedAccountData((prevData) =>
      prevData.map((data, i) => {
        if (
          name === UPDATE_TYPE.ACCOUNT_ID &&
          value === null &&
          data.Id === accountId
        ) {
          return { ...data, Debit: 0, Credit: 0 };
        }  else {
          return { ...data };
        }
      })
    );
 useEffect(() => {

    console.log('State updated:', selectedAccountData);
  }, [selectedAccountData]);
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code.  It would help if you provided sample data and the external values in your conditional

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is likely due to the asynchronous nature of state updates in React. When you call setSelectedAccountData, React doesn't immediately update the state. Instead, it schedules an update, and the new state value is not available right after the call.

To log the updated state, you should use the callback function provided by setSelectedAccountData:

```
setSelectedAccountData((prevData) => {
  const updatedData = prevData.map((data, i) => {
    if (
      name === UPDATE_TYPE.ACCOUNT_ID &&
      value === null &&
      data.Id === accountId
    ) {
      return { ...data, Debit: 0, Credit: 0 };
    } else {
      return { ...data };
    }
  });

  // Log the updated state here
  console.log('State updated:', updatedData);

  return updatedData; // Return the updated data to set the state
});
```

By doing this, you ensure that you are logging the state after it has been updated.

Your useEffect should then correctly log the updated state:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('State updated:', selectedAccountData);
}, [selectedAccountData]);
```